# Advice for handling permissions in SAP

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I've created a solution where I created an authorization object which controls what can a user handle or watch in the program. This authorization object is defined with 3 elements:

- Process
- Activity
- Material group

Through transaction 'PFCG' the BC creates the profiles according the requests that users make to have permission to some module of the program. For example, a user or a group of users will access to process 'A1' (Data update), activity '01' (Aproval) and material group 'A0A00001'. This means that these users could only aprove for process 'A1' the data for material group 'A0A00001'.

My problem here is that managers of the areas have told me that they feel uncomfortable making requests to the BC for permissions because they think that they should manage those profiles, and if they want to change those permissions they would like to have the control of them directly instead of making requests.

This is a situation where I don't know what to do, I have thought that I would make Z tables and a Z program to emulate those permissions exactly as they are handled now with transaction 'PFCG' but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Another thing that I have thought is to create a Z program that would be a layer of transaction 'PFCG' to automate the profiles for this authorization objects but in this case I don't know where to start because I would have to investigate if is there a BAPI for creating profiles and how to manage all the issues related with this management.

The other thing is leave it like that and do nothing, but sincerely I don't know what to do.

Do you have any suggestion on this issue? What can be done in this situation?

Comment: Is "training the managers to maintain their own roles" an option? It's not that hard, after all... And "feeling uncomfortable" should not be a major decision factor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you mean to let them access to transaction 'PFCG'? '"feeling uncomfortable" should not be a major decision factor' I agree with that.

Comment: Yes. It should be possible to restrict access to PFCG so that they can't issue arbitrary permissions or modify roles outside their assigned area.

Comment: Seems promising that option. I'll talk with the system administrator. He's reluctant to share administration tools like ' PFCG' but at least I can try.